# Kernels of integral transform and linear transformation

Tags: vector-spaces, integral-transforms

Is there any relation between the $kernel$ of an $integral \ transform$ and the $kernel$ of a $linear \ transformation$?

Comment: That would be kernel knowledge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the uses are unrelated. See the [Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics (K)](http://jeff560.tripod.com/k.html).

> The use of kernel in algebra appears to be unrelated to its use in integral equations and Fourier analysis. The OED gives the following quotation from Pontrjagin's Topological Groups i. 11 (translated by E. Lehmer 1946) "The set of all the elements of the group G which go into the identity of the group G* under the homomorphism g is called the kernel of this homomorphism."